# Country name is in an unexpected language when filtering search results

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

For some reason, my country name, Poland, is written in German when I filter jobs search results. I have my language set to English, so I really have no idea where it's coming from.

> [image: screenshot of the issue]

Edit: when I type in "Warszawa" into the search box, I get "Warszawa, Polska", however after I refresh the page or use the "back to search results" link I get "Warszawa, Polen".

Comment: Didn't you notice?? ;-)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think you're one of the few that can  make that joke ...

Comment: we're using Google Maps on our autocomplete... any chance you've been using Google Maps in German? I'm not able to reproduce on my end... what exactly did you write into it? if you didn't write anything, can you get me the URL you're on?

Comment: I get "Warschau, Polen" with de-DE as the main browser language, so that's probably not it. MIght still be worth checking your browser's `accept-language` string.

Comment: Someone needs to tell the Simpsons they need to do a German equivalent to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uDXtVlG2VW0) so we have something to post in this kind of situation.

Comment: Heh, your username fits in like a glove https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnWLB.png

Comment: @Pekka웃 Well, but Hitler doesn't rest in a glass coffin' :-P

Comment: If it's any help, this looks more like Swedish (my native language) to me than German.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I suppose he would have to rise from the depths of some Russian archive or another! Not nearly as dramatic a comeback though, agreed.

Comment: @g3rv4 the problem happens on refresh, and the url is `https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/developer-jobs-in-warszawa?sort=i`. I'm getting it and everything of mine is set in English. Chrome 58 and Windows 10.

Comment: Refreshing this url `https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=i&l=Warszawa%2C+Poland&d=20&u=Km` (which has Poland) leads to the one in my comment above

Comment: @CalvT thanks! I've been able to reproduce it... working on a fix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright... mystery solved. We had one job that had "Warszawa, Polen" as its location, due to the customer that created it using our product in German. As we build our landing pages based on the details of the currently running jobs, `developer-jobs-in-warszawa` was picking up the details from that particular job.

The job details were in English, but Google Maps was shown in German for them and that's why the location was set in German. I went ahead and updated it, so there're no jobs with that location now.

If you visit `https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/developer-jobs-in-warszawa`, the system now won't treat it as a "known location", but it will still get relevant results. And `https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/developer-jobs-in-warsaw` shows, as before, "Warsaw, Poland".